# Encontrar la solución particular de: xy(1+y^2 )dx-(1+x^2 )dy=0, sabiendo que: y(0) = 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Me he atascado con este problema, si pudieran ayudarme para completar la solución, tal vez así pueda ver cuál es mi error. Algo no estoy haciendo bien, ayúnenme a mejorar por favor. gracias.

-dy(X)/ (X^2 + 1) + x (y(x^2) +1) y(x) = 0

dy(X)/dx =(x(y(x) ^2 + 1) y (x)) / (x^2 + 1)

dy(x) /dx = x (y(x) ^3 + y (x)) / (x^2 + 1)

Comment: I don't understand your language, but your equation shouldn't be only in the title.

Comment: Find the particular solution of: (xy(1 + y^2)) dx - (1 + x^2)dy = 0, knowing that: y(0) = 1

Comment: cual es tu avance?

Comment: Cómo vamos a poder a ver cuál es tu error cuando no muestras tu solución?

Comment: -dy(X)/ (X^2 + 1) + x (y(x^2) +1) y(x) = 0
dy(X)/dx =(x(y(x) ^2 + 1) y (x)) / (x^2 + 1)

dy(x) /dx = x (y(x) ^3 + y (x)) / (x^2 + 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can just rewrite the equation in this way:
$\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{y(1+y^2)}dy$, and then integrate both sides.
$\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\int \frac{1}{y(1+y^2)}dy$

$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx=\int \frac{1+y^2-y^2}{y(1+y^2)}dy$

The first integral it's just equal to: $\frac{1}{2}ln(1+x^2)$, and the second integral can be broken in 2:

$\int \frac{1+y^2-y^2}{y(1+y^2)}dy=\int \frac{1+y^2-y^2}{y(1+y^2)}dy-\int \frac{y^2}{y(1+y^2)}dy=\int \frac{1}{y}dy-\int \frac{y}{1+y^2}dy=ln(y)-\frac{1}{2}ln(1+y^2)$

In the end we get: $\frac{1}{2}ln(1+x^2)=ln(y)-\frac{1}{2}ln(1+y^2)+c$

Now we can apply the exponential function on both sides and get:

$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac{cy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$

And to find $c$ we can just substitute $x=0$ and $y=1$ in the expression.

$\sqrt{1+0^2}=\frac{c*1}{\sqrt{1+1^2}}$;
$1=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$;  $c=\sqrt{2}$

So the final expression is:

$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac{y\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$

Comment: Then continue via $1+x^2-y^2+x^2y^2=0$ to $y=\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}$.